# Can't get X11 forwarding working with XQuartz

Tags: command-line, ssh, ventura, x11, xquartz

I'm on Ventura. I'm trying to log in to a remote Linux machine with X11 forwarding enabled. I followed these steps:

1. Install XQuartz (from the downloadable package on their website, not from `brew`).
2. Reboot my Mac
3. Enable "allow connections from network clients" in XQuartz
4. Ensure X11 forwarding is enabled in the remote's `sshd_config` and restart remote `sshd`
5. Disable the firewall on my Mac
6. `ssh -X user@remote` from the terminal within XQuartz
7. Confirm that the `DISPLAY` env var is set on the remote
8. `xterm` on the remote

And nothing happens; `xterm` just freezes. There are no error messages, but also no windows appear.

I've also tried:

- Enabling/disabling "authenticate connections" in XQuartz
- `ssh -Y` instead of `ssh -X`
- Manually setting the remote `DISPLAY` variable to `my_ip_address:0`
- Waiting for a few minutes after running `xterm` just in case I was being impatient

But all have the same effect: running `xterm` just hangs with no errors.

What else can I try?

Comment: What is the value of $DISPLAY